# Build up UICollectionView from center

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm facing a problem where I want to realize a `UICollectionView` that essentially builds up from the center.

Let's say I have this view which shows a list of people:

[image: First view]

When the user keeps adding multiple persons using the **+**, I want the CollectionView to expand but stay in the center of the view:

[image] [image]

How do I realize this behavior?

Comment: Please provide your code here.

Comment: Well, I'm just using the default implementation of a `UICollectionView` right now but that one starts, as you know, in the top left corner of the view.

Comment: How do you implement + button?

Comment: I don't see your problem at all; create a custom layout for your collection view and set up the desired layout there.

Comment: @holex I might be heavily overthinking this but still would not know how to do so.

Comment: @James, a full screen sized `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`; there are thousand examples on the net but here is the official one for a good start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using autolayout and size classes then you can set "center" is a collection view like this...

```
[collectionView setCenter:self.view.center];
```

And if autolayout is enabled and you are using it then do this...

1. Set CenterX and CenterY constrains of collection view
2. Set Height and width constraints of collection view

Comment: For this to work wouldn't you have to keep changing the height of the colelctionview otherwise the cells would be positioned at the top of the screen as usual (if the collectionview was full height).

Comment: Then you need to give leading, top, trailing and bottom  constraints with low priority so It remains in screen

Comment: ...and check/change the height of the collection view every time new cells are added for it to show all the cells and to remain in the center. Maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: Exactly my thoughts @JoeBenton

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a custom flow layout, an alternative approach would be to have a full height collection view as normal and then set a top and bottom inset to visually center the cells:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{

    let inset = (collectionView.frame.size.height - ((COUNT_OF_CELLS / CELLS_PER_ROW) * HEIGHT_OF_CELL) / 2)
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, 0, inset, 0);
}
```

You will need to keep track of the total number of cells, number of cells on a row, and the cells height for the calculation to work right.